# Assigning returned pointer to another returned pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Searched on Google for a long time. Nothing comes up.

```
class queue {
public:
    item* getback() {
        return back;
    }
    item* getfront() {
        return front;
    }
    void push(const char* msg);
    const char* pop();
private:
    item* back;
    item* front;
};

class doublequeue {
public:
    doublequeue() {
        read.getback() = send.getfront(); // HERE!!!
    }
private:
    queue read;
    queue send;
};
```

On the line that says "HERE!!!", read is underlined in red in MSVC++ 2012. The error is something to do with the lvalue not being a valid lvalue.

I understand how to overload the assignment operator. I understand that when you return an int, to assign it to something it must be returned as a reference, because you can't say 2 = 3 + 5. I get it. But with pointers, when you say a pointer is equal to another, you're just making them point to the same spot in memory right? It's not like I'm returning the address, I'm returning a pointer.

Comment: A pointer is just like a special `int` that holds an address. So what holds for `int` holds for pointers.

Comment: You can validly do this if you change `item* getfront() { // ` to  `item*& getfront() { //`

Comment: So are the two accessor functions actually returning addresses?

Comment: It's funny because I actually gave that a shot, but I hate having to do *&! It's so messy looking. Makes it look like I've messed up somewhere.

Comment: Another X-Y problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was just trying to make the pointer "back" within read, and the pointer "front" within send point to the same item.

Comment: No, assigning to pointers works exactly like assigning to anything else, and pointer variables work exactly like other variables. It may help to think of them as indexes into the big array that we call "RAM".

Comment: @thelittlegumnut If you would point them to the *same* `item`, you would attach the entire send queue to the back of the read queue. Do you mean that the items should have the same *value* (`*read.getback() = *send.getfront()`)?

Comment: @molbdino Actually yes. It might seem weird, but that's just because of the naming convention. It's an implementation specific queue so I didn't expect anyone to know what I meant by send and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer you return from getback() is a separate object from your member back. The getback() function returns a copy of the member, and the copy has no identity. It is a temporary, which is not an lvalue. Assigning to it doesn't make a lot of sense, hence the error message. Even if you did assign to it, it would not change your back member.

To assign to the member, you could return a reference to it and assign to that. Or you could return a pointer to your member and assign to the result of the dereferenced pointer. Or you could use a setter function. Or you could just make back and front public, since that is essentially what you are wanting anyway and is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Does it mean something?

```
int foo()
{ return 10; }

foo() = 20;
```

The return type is not L-value, and thus cannot be assigned. Treat `int*` as `int`, and you will understand it is not possible to assign something to R-value.

Answer (score 0):

> understand that when you return an int, to assign it to something it must be returned as a reference, because you can't say 2 = 3 + 5.

That's correct. It's also true for pointers.

> But with pointers, when you say a pointer is equal to another, you're just making them point to the same spot in memory right?

Also correct. Assigning a pointer would do that. Just like assigning an integer would give the left hand integer the same value as on the right hand side of the assignment operator. In both cases the left side must not be a temporary.

> It's not like I'm returning the address, I'm returning a pointer.

The value of a pointer **is** a memory address. There is no difference in returning an address or returning a pointer.